# file not found even though it exists - ESET Endpoint Antivirus activation problem

Tags: files

I have succesfully installed EST Endpoint Antivirus on Ubuntu 22.04.

Activation fails as follows:

```
 /opt/eset/eea/sbin/lic --key XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
 bash: /opt/eset/eea/sbin/lic --key: No such file or directory
```

but this file does exist, indeed. The same happens with all other activation options, including file activation.

I tried to troubleshoot, but at no avail:

```
 file /opt/eset/eea/sbin/lic
 /opt/eset/eea/sbin/lic: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

The approaches suggested from askubuntu.com and other linux forums failed as well. Also this interpreter seems to be installed.

Maybe someone of this community knows what to do....

Comment: That "space" between `...lic` and `--key` is ___not really the ASCII space character___, but it as a character with ASCII code 160 (that resembles the space). Delete it and retype it using the "space bar".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied the code from the eset documentation website. The terminal was not interpreting the space correctly. Replace above the mentioned space between lic and --key by space bar, as suggested by @FedKad. Now it works. It interpreted it as a different ASCII code, resembling a space.